# reading tweets using Rstudio

Tags: oauth

I am trying to read tweets related to Zika virus and have created an application in twitter, but not able to connect to twitter through R. I have tried following commands

```
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "my consumer key"
consumerSecret <- "my consumer secret key"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=reqURL,
                             accessURL=accessURL,
                             authURL=authURL)
twitCred$handshake()
```

immediately after this I get this error message:

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
>   Could not resolve host: api.twitter.com

Please help me I have installed following packages

```
library("bitops", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
library("digest", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
library("RCurl", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
library("rjson", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
library("ROAuth", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
library("twitteR", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making authentication with R and Twitter too complex.  From several blogs which I read, all you need to do is make one call to `setup_twitter_oauth()` and you should be good to go:

```
consumer_key    <- "your_consumer_key"
consumer_secret <- "your_consumer_secret"
access_token    <- "your_access_token"
access_secret   <- "your_access_secret"

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

In order to obtain an access token and secret, you will have to create a Twitter application from the Twitter settings page, and generate them manually.

Please read through [this blog](http://www.r-bloggers.com/setting-up-the-twitter-r-package-for-text-analytics/) for a step-by-step guide on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I have tried setup_twitter_oauth() command also. It still gives error . Even I have tried the way given in the blog suggested by you.

Comment: What error do you get when using the approach suggested in my answer?

Comment: > consumer_key <- "consumer key"
> consumer_secret <-" consumer secrete key"
> access_token <- "dKH9CcPjhVjfxuZByl4DMLRyfsrJFLS"
> access_secret <- "CC6JruhrQ2SmgpbV850eOryVWxL5bnQ0FA7SmGvHCuiJ5"
> setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 1
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
>